# Mixamo addon: linear extrapolation not serving to LOOP this run cycle properly

Tags: animation, mixamo

I have this character that I added a run animation to I downloaded from Mixamo I used the mixamo add-on to add the animation and I went to the graph editor and selected all keyframes and chose make cyclic when I get to the part that you normally do you select shift E and choose linear extrapolation after selecting the Z location in that box of properties on the left I don't know what it's called ....and selecting 1 keyframe and hitting L on your keyboard.... To select all Z location keyframes, OF course:).... That didn't work

I uploaded my file :  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mz6TkqndYk8H_fJLGajaBGqI0EKOvJ_v/view?usp=sharing

The thing is when I select one keyframe of the Z location and hit L only two keyframes get selected

on the rest of the line of the z location property which is extended as far as the animation is made cyclic there are no other key frames even though the blue line is there... As you can see here[image]  see right before I took that picture I selected one keyframe and hit L that's all that was selected when I choose shift e and chose linear extrapolation nothing really changes

can you help me with this... And really explain it well so I could master IT and other people that find this could master looping walk and run cycles with the mixamo add-on... that information was hard to find on the web and I've been trying to master this for a whiLE... A comprehensive tutorial where that's a part would be key

Comment: The answer is Hey MIXAMO can you help? you're a aDobe and we can't seem to figure out how to loop a walk cycle using your addon... anybody from Adobe find this and help us out

Answer (score 1):

What I see there why this animation might not loop properly is this, if you loop the Z location like in your screenshot, it loops better if the last keyframe is the same as the first. But that brings us to how the cyclic animation you added works and why you can only select two keyframes:

You can only select two keyframes for Z location because there are just two keyframes. When you opened the context menu with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, it's not just saying *Make Cyclic*, but *Make Cyclic (F-Modifier)*. This means, it puts a modifier on the curve which you can find in the *Modifiers* tab of the *Side Panel*:

[image: cycles modifier]

Now like object modifiers don't create real vertices, the *Cycles* modifier generates no real keyframes - just like e.g. a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, where you cannot access the new vertices in *Edit Mode* unless you apply the modifier. Which in this case means, when you change the two keyframes you have, this automatically changes the other keyframes as well.

As I said before, a cyclic animation on the Z location works better if the last keyframe is the same as the first or else it will jump weirdly. Or if your intention is to have it continuously go higher on the Z axis, the modifier should be set to *Repeat with Offset* instead of *Repeat Motion*.

But if you now want to make the keyframes editable to place them individually, you have to go to the menu *Key* and choose *Bake Curve* and hit *OK*. A baked curve is not editable yet, it just applied the modifier. To get keyframes, you have to go to the menu again and choose *Un-Bake Curve*.

But beware: the good thing now is, you have keyframes for the whole curve. The bad thing is, first of all they are just in the *Start/End* range which is set for the animation, if you want to extend it you have to do it manually. The next and even worse thing is, you have keyframes on each single frame - even if it is just a simple linear curve going straight from one position to another.

[image: bake curve]

[image: un-baked curve]

Comment: OK there was a little confusion.. In the tutorial somehow he extended his walk cycle using the Z location in my file that I uploaded the walk cycle obviously extends in the y location I mean the run cycle I need to know how to simply extend the run cycle so he keeps on running can you give me step by step instructions precisely because I tried your methods nothing really seemed to work I tried your message on the Y location that is...

Comment: I guess that would be _Repeat with Offset_ which I mention in my answer. However, when I tried that it didn't really work because there seemed to be more parts involved in the movement - but to be honest, there are so many keyframed bones and I didn't have a real overview which does what nor did I have the time to sort this all out. To get this working correctly you have to find you out which parts you need to move...

Comment: been trying that it's just a standard  Mixamo animation Applied using mixamo addon and that's why I posted this post because I can't find that